# how to read html file on Django

Tags: python, html, css, django

I started make a website for my school project, i use Django Frameworks 
i want to make my homepage website, i already have html file, then what should i do to make Django read my homepage 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjF6o.png)
this is my urls.py on main folder

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('katalog/', include('katalog.urls')),
    path('', ) #what should i write here?
]
```

Comment: In katalog folder, create urls.py and import your view function(if created) which renders html file and pass inside path function.

Comment: Simple: `path('some-path/', views.path_function)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

django doc: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/#example, it offers the below example

```
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('articles/2003/', views.special_case_2003),
```

You have to create in your apps views.py file a FBV or CBV, the easiest is a FBV like below:

```
def someview(request):
    context={}#if you want to add objects to the front end
    return render(request, 'yourhtmlfile', context)
```

and then import it in your urls.py:

```
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('home/', views.someview),
```

Comment: very easily you wrote 'yourhtmlfile' without describing its important details